# HEX-/RGB-colors in Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

I'd appreciate to be able to use my Linux colorscheme in Terminal.

Is there a way I can specify HEX-codes or maybe RGB-values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the colors as RGB from the second tab of the color picker:

[image]

You can specify a color as a hex code by installing [Hex Color Picker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/visit/).